# how do i add a key-value pair to an object in state of functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i've seen some stuff about computed property names for class components, is there a similar solution for functional components?

i have an initial state of {}.

```
const [choice, setChoice] = useState({})
```

as a button clicks, i'd like to add a new k:v to it dynamically.

```
onClick={()=>{ 
setChoice( props.choice[Key]=[Val] );
}
```

this doesn't seem to work...

and i'm hoping to add to the choice variable, like so: {"key":"val","key1":"val1",etc..)

i've also tried this:

```
class Choice {
    constructor(key, value){
      this.key = key,
      this.value = value
    }
  }
```

but not sure how to adjust the onClick for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem comes from your accessor for `choice` in the onClick function. The good syntax should be (because choice is accessible directly as a variable in your component)

```
onClick={()=>{ 
setChoice( { ...choice, key:val } ); 
}
```

1. `choice` is state variable, so directly accessible by its name. No need to link to your component props with props.choice
2. setChoice should take as an argument the original variable, plus the new key/value pair. Thus the destructuring of ...choice and the added member variable key:value.

Edit:
if you want your updates to be more sound with the React way, you should use the callback syntax. Finally you would have

```
setChoice(choice => { return {...choice, key:val}})
```

This preventing some noodling, coming from the asynchronous nature of state updates in React.

Comment: this is perfect! i added props because it's taking place in an 'outer' component, props being passed to a buttonmaker.  for completion, i used ```{...props.choice,[key]:val}```

Comment: You should not use the previous state like this in useState handler, this will not ensure that the last state will be used when the useState is actually called.

Comment: if i do this, i get ```Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ","```  i had to first do ```const choice1 = props.choice``` then do that in case someone is following

Comment: coming from the arrow syntax for `choice => {choice, key:val}`. I have corrected the edit

Answer (score 1):

To add to the current state a new key value pair:

```
onClick={() => {
    setChoice( currentState => {
        return {...currentState, Key:Val}
        }
}}
```

The handler on set state has this overload that let's you use the previous state and add to it.

Comment: thank you. do you recommend using the ```return``` keyword vs wrapping in ()?

Comment: No difference, they do the same